# Carts in Magento2 REST API and Front-end

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I was able to sign in using /rest/V1/integration/customer/token and add items to cart. How do I view the cart(items I added using REST API) from front-end?

Comment: refer this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183526/magento-2-regsitered-user-add-to-cart-api/189512#189512

Answer (score 0):

just make get request to

```
V1/carts/mine/items
```

You should get a json response with the data.

The cart needs to be create first, you do that by posting to

```
V1/carts/mine
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.OP wants to view the cart in the Magento storefront, not list the items in the API.

Comment: @DougMcLean the store front doesn't use rest api... storefront != frontend..

Comment: Magento themselves treat the two terms as synonymous, pretty much: see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_and_areas.html. But we are at risk of arguing over semantics. My understanding of the question is that OP wants to generate a cart via the API, add items to it via the API, but then link to the storefront and have that cart shown there. It's a requirement I've seen before: browse and pick via an app, but then be sent to a single point of checkout (the storefront) to complete the order.

Comment: I see your point.. And magento should use the term more visely as the store front is made from both backend (PHP) and frontend (HTML/JS/CSS).. Guess we just assume different things.. OP talked about managed to login using rest so I was just assuming that he/she was talking about making at xhr request to post cart items and then retrieving them in the same way :)

Comment: Guess it´s good that we post about both options here as comments :)