# Magento 2 regsitered user add to cart API

Tags: magento2, api, addtocart

In postman , I tried to add the product to the cart for registered user using this API :

> /rest/V1/carts/mine

but I am facing an error like

```
{
    "message": "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources",
    "parameters": {
        "resources": "self"
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop posting same issue continuously , check here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183465/magento2-add-to-cart-rest-api

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below steps by replacing your domain URL and use your customer credentials to login and do the add to cart.

**Step 1:-**

Get the registered user login details(from website) so that you will get authentication key hence follow the below step first

note:- please note down the response token/key it will useful for next following steps at header section

**Method:-** POST

**API:-** http://yoursite.com/rest/V1/integration/customer/token?username=test@gmail.com&password=test@123

screenshot:- 
[[image: Customer Authentication with Magento through Postman]]

**Step 2:-**

Create Cart using below API call along with the adding header section keys and values as shown below and it will generate cart id.

**Method:-** POST

**API:-** http://yoursite.com/rest/V1/carts/mine

screenshot:- 
[[image: Create new cart in Magento through Postman]]

**Step 3:-** 
Add item to Cart

**Method:-** POST

**API:-**  http://yoursite.com/rest/V1/carts/mine/items

**Body section:**
{
    "cart_item": {
        "quote_id": "15",
        "sku": "24-MB03",
        "qty": 1
    }
}

screenshot:- 
[[image: Add a item to cart in Magento through Postman]]

Note:- don't forget to add authentication key and value & Content-Type is application/JSON in the postman app at header section. Based on product type this input has to vary.

**Step 4:-**

Get Cart details with cart items

**Method:-** GET

**API:-**  http://yoursite.com/rest/V1/carts/mine

screenshot:- 
  [[image: get Cart details/items from Magento through Postman]]

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. I got the token and after that sending request to `/rest/default/V1/carts/mine`. Any idea?

Comment: magento ver 1.9.2.3,I am work with REST API in POSTMAN, i have all oAuth 1.0 details like Consumer Key,Consumer Secret,Access Token,Token Secret. Now i moved to oAuth 2.0, how can i get my all oAuth 2.0 details? @Nagaraju Kasa